# Symfony: passing weird port on login redirect

Tags: php, symfony

I am quite new to Symfony, but having issues with login redirect. Here is a snip of my `security.yml` config:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        anonymous: ~
        pattern: ^/login
        simple_form:
            authenticator: app.api_authenticator
            login_path: login
            check_path: login

            username_parameter: login[username]
            password_parameter: login[password]

            default_target_path: home
            always_use_default_target_path: true
        provider: api
        context: main

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.auth_token_authenticator
        stateless: true
        context: main
```

I have setup local instance running on `https://localhost`. When I go to login page (`https://localhost/login`) and submit the right credentials, Symfony redirects me to `https://localhost:0/home` instead of expected `https://localhost/home`. Any ideas what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a service defined (in services.yml) corresponding to app.auth_token_authenticator?

Comment: Yes, I do. If I wouldn't then I assume I would get an error.

Comment: I figured so, but did not want to assume. Can you tell us what the service definition looks like?

Comment: do you have found a solution ? @baa2w

Answer (score 0):

I think `login_path` and `login_check` should not be the same route.

```
login:
    /***/           
    check_path: /login_check
    login_path: /login
    /***/
```

Comment: Why is that? Even official Symfony documentation has an example where these paths are same: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Comment: and what about this mention? `The login_path and check_path can also be route names (but cannot have mandatory wildcards - e.g. /login/{foo} where foo has no default value).`

Comment: Yes, in my example, the `login` is actually a route name.